# How to select an 'outer' HTML element with a certain tag within it in JSOUP?

Tags: java, html, parsing, css-selectors, jsoup

So, say I have this HTML block here: (this is Java JSOUP BTW)

```
<div class="menuitem"> <span class="ul">Creamy Broccoli Cheddar Soup</span><img class="icon" alt="Vegetarian">
```

Right now I have a list of elements (as Elements type) and I want to select the  elements, but only ones that have an attribute as "Vegetarian" in the alt="" part of the img tag within it.

Right now I can select based on if it's Vegetarian for example by doing

meals.select("img[alt=vegetarian]")

but this only returns the actual img tags as elements, thus losing the name of the object (which is Creamy Broccoli Cheddar Soup in the above example)

How do I select the div part of the element but still make sure the img tag within has a certain attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over all the `div` elements of class `menuitem`, and check at each iteration if `meals.select("img[alt=vegetarian]").size() > 0`.